# CFLocaleCopyCurrent stale value

Tags: c++, macos, foundation, core-foundation

At my workplace, our app determines the locale of the user session by using a code that is similar to below (though there are various layers of code it passes through before it reaches here at the time of startup, so the problem is/may not evident by running the code below)

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>  
#include <vector>  
#include <memory>  

  // Reference release  
    struct reference_close  
    {  
        void operator()(const void *ref) const  
        {  
            CFRelease(static_cast<CFTypeRef>(ref));  
        }  
    }; // end of reference_close structure  

    typedef std::unique_ptr<const void, reference_close>  reference_uptr;  

    std::string get_user_locale()  
    {  
        reference_uptr  ref_ptr(CFLocaleCopyCurrent());  
        CFLocaleRef    locale_ref(static_cast<CFLocaleRef>(ref_ptr.get()));  
        if (locale_ref == nullptr)  
        {  
            return std::string();  
        }  
        const size_t      default_size(128);  
        std::vector<char>  buff(default_size);  
        CFStringRef        str_ref(CFLocaleGetIdentifier(locale_ref));  

      if (str_ref != nullptr)  
        {  
            CFIndex  len(CFStringGetLength(str_ref) + 1);  
            if (len > boost::numeric_cast<CFIndex>(default_size))  
            {  
                buff.resize(len);  
            }  

            buff[0] = 0;  
            if (!CFStringGetCString(str_ref, &buff[0], len, kCFStringEncodingISOLatin1))  
            {  
                return std::string();  
            }  
        }  

        return std::string(&buff[0]);  
    } // end of get_user_locale()  

int main()  
{  
    std::cout << "get_user_locale() : "<<get_user_locale() << std::endl;  

    return 0;  
}
```

The app has a well defined bundle structure with necessary resources and localization resource directories e.g `Contents/Resources/ja.lproj`

Lately, we are facing an issue wherein we do the following

1) Change the system language and country in the preferences e.g. change from en_US to ja_JP

2) Reboot the machine

3) Launch the app and see the erroneous output e.g en_JP

4) Re-launch the app to get the correct answer as ja_JP

I have read the documentation of [CFLocaleCopyCurrent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542508-cflocalecopycurrent) which states that

> Settings you get from this locale do not change as a user's
>   preferences are changed so that your operations are consistent.
>   Typically you perform some operations on the returned object and then
>   release it. Since the returned object may be cached, you do not need
>   to hold on to it indefinitely.

I also checked the another documentation on [lifetime of CFLocale](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFLocales/Articles/CFLocaleWorking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002241-164844) which states that

> The object you get back from CFLocaleCopyCurrent does not change when
>   the user changes their Preferences settings. Moreover, the object
>   itself may be cached by the runtime system, so successive calls of
>   CFLocaleCopyCurrent may return the same object, even if a user has
>   changed preference settings. If you want to ensure that your locale
>   settings are consistent with user preferences, you must synchronize
>   preferences and get a new locale object with CFLocaleCopyCurrent.

Given this info, I tried to incorporate `CFPreferencesSynchronize` and/or `CFPreferencesSynchronize` in the app code (just before I call the `CFLocaleCopyCurrent`) to get the most updated locale. But no luck.

Do I need to do anything extra to make sure that I get the most recent/updated value of locale object from the system preferences ?

Comment: Why not use `[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]`?  That code looks very poorly written anyway.

Comment: @trojanfoe Is there any C++ alternative of `autoupdatingCurrentLocale` for `CFLocale` class ? I am finding it difficult to mix Objective C code in my C++ code.

Comment: You just need to implement the C++ within a `.mm` file and it will be compiled as Objective-C++.  I will add an answer with some (untested) example code.

Comment: The documentation of `CFLocaleCopyCurrent` says "The language of the current locale may not correspond to the language at the first index in the AppleLanguages array from user defaults.". `en_JP` is correct.

Comment: @Willeke Hmm, its frustrating to see that it gives back the incorrect language the first time (`en_JP`) and correct one afterwards (`ja_JP`).

Comment: `en_JP` is a correct locale id. If you want to get the preffered language, use `CFLocaleCopyPreferredLanguages()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1414388-autoupdatingcurrentlocale?language=objc) which will change as the user changes their locale settings, but as `NSLocale` is an Objective-C class you will need to implement glue code as Objective-C++.

Here is some untested example code, giving you the idea:

Create a file called `AppleLocale.mm` (unless of course your project is for Apple platforms only so doesn't need the `Apple` name prefix).

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

std::string get_user_locale()
{
    NSLocale* locale = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];
    return std::string([[locale localeIdentifier] UTF8String]);
}
```

Note: You'll need a function prototype in some header as well, of course.

Comment: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]: unrecognized selector sent to class`

Comment: I am, now, trying to ascertain the reasons for above runtime error.

Comment: @Recker I don't understand that crash.  See [this Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale?language=objc) for very similar usage.

Comment: Hmm, this code is crashing. I am trying to understand why such simple use case would fail with a stack.

Comment: Well it's almost certainly something outside the scope of your question.