# NSSLocale identifier results in runtime crash with a stack

Tags: c++, macos, objective-c++, foundation, core-foundation

I posted a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58713505/1410711) earlier to get the most updated locale identifier from the user preference settings.
Here is the answer that I got.

```
 #include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    std::string get_user_locale()
    {
        NSLocale* locale = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];
        return std::string([[locale localeIdentifier] UTF8String]);
    }

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Locale is " << get_user_locale() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I created a standalone .mm file and tried to print the locale identifier string but the app fails with following stack

```
2019-11-06 05:40:12.879 App[9062:303135] +[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff8f86c458
2019-11-06 05:40:12.894 App[9062:303135] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff8f86c458'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff36daeecd __exceptionPreprocess + 256
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff62e66720 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff36e2c1c5 __CFExceptionProem + 0
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff36d50b40 ___forwarding___ + 1486
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff36d504e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
        5   testfun                             0x000000010e72096a main + 58
        6   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff63f34ed9 start + 1
        7   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Locale is 

Abort (core dumped)
```

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Please show the link command.  I want to ensure the `Foundation` framework is being linked.

Comment: @trojanfoe Unfortunately, I can not post the link command as it contains lots of IP related artifacts. But I checked and confirmed that `Foundation` is indeed being linked.

Comment: Please split that source file out to a single file and build and link it away from your product and see if that works.  When it does work you know it's likely a build/link setting related to your product, which will be difficult to diagnose given it's commercially sensitive nature.

Comment: The stack trace here suggests this might not be a Cocoa app, or if it is, the `NSLocale` method is being called before `NSApplicationLoad()`/`NSApplicationMain()` has been called, so it's possible something in the Foundation library isn't initialised yet. Have you checked if your use case can be covered by [`CFLocale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cflocale?language=objc) APIs?

Comment: @pmdj Please see the linked question. The reason why I need to use this is because the `CFLocale` API is returning cached/stale value. I hope that with this one, I can get the most updated one albeit in C++ code. And yes, you are right, this is not a Cocoa app. I just created a plain .mm file and compiled/ran it from command line instead of XCode.